# How to check if key exist in data, if exist then do for loop else ignore using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I have data(dictionary format) that contains keys and values, I want to display that data using list comprehensions.

data = {
'memberships': 'type of membership'
}

**Note:** The data is different for each profile(for eg: **membership** is available for only few users.)

**Attempt1:**

```
memberships = [data['memberships'][mem] for mem in data['memberships']]
print(memberships)
```

The above code is working for the users having a membership. If membership does not exist it will thrown an KeyError.

**Attempt2:**

```
memberships =[data['memberships'][mem] for mem in data['memberships'] if 'memberships' in data]
```

**Attemp3:**

```
memberships=[data['memberships'][mem] if "memberships" in data else '' for mem in data['memberships']]
```

I tried but failed with KeyError for all the attempts. I want to check the membership(key) if exists I will loop and display it else ignoring

Comment: The question is not very clear. I am guessing that `data` is itself a variable that loops over some profiles? Also, why are you even doing a list comprehension over `data['memberships']`? what is the transformation you are trying to achieve? Perhaps a short but complete example of data would help you (and it would certainly help us), but I suspect you are mixing up two nested loops here.

Comment: please provide a larger sample of `data` dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can always use an if statement:

```
if 'membership' in data.keys():
    memberships = [data['memberships'][mem] for mem in data['memberships']]
    print(memberships)
else:
    #Do something else if you wish
    pass
```

Another option (if it suits your code better) is to use try and except, although I doubt you need this approach:

```
try:
    #Will try to execute this code
    memberships = [data['memberships'][mem] for mem in data['memberships']]
    print(memberships)

except:
    #If a KeyError occurs, the try block will stop and this part of the code will execute
    pass
```

Hope this helps! If you have any questions with my answer feel free to ask.